# Adobe Edge slide show conflict with jquery ui

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, adobe-edge

I have made slide show in adobe edge

when i use it in asp.net mvc3 razor view engine my jquery 1.8 ui (modal dialog, drag & drop) does not working anymore

Does anybody knows how i can solve this problem?

Comment: Is there a javascript error? Seems like an error is probably being thrown which would break the js on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Edge animate uses jquery 1.7 by default. it might be a duplication of jquery calles so try to remove edge call or replace it to the 1.8 version.